# How do I change the data type for a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to change the data type of multiple columns from float to int.  What is the simplest way to do this?

There is no data to worry about, yet.

Comment: Just to make this explicit, the answers below (using `ALTER TABLE`) will, in fact, work even if the column already contains data. However, converting a float column into an integer column will cause any non-integer values in it to be rounded to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 1252, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INTEGER;
```

This will change the datatype of given column

Depending on how many columns you wish to modify it might be best to generate a script, or use some kind of mysql client GUI

Comment: Friendly reminder - The default for columns is NULLABLE, so if you have a NOT NULL column, don't forget to use "MODIFY columnname INTEGER NOT NULL" or else you will change your column from NOT NULL to NULL.

Comment: Will alter table delete the data on the table or fail on the execution if something is not complaint with the new column type?

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INTEGER unsigned; <-- if you care about the new column being unsigned. Was my case.

Comment: I think @Despertars warning might also be relevant for keeping any specifications of CHARSET or COLLATE.

Answer (score 55):

```
alter table table_name modify column_name int(5)
```

Answer (score 46):

You can also use this:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename] CHANGE [columnName] [columnName] DECIMAL (10,2)
```

Answer (score 18):

If you want to change all columns of a certain type to another type, you can generate queries using a query like this:

```
select distinct concat('alter table ',
                       table_name,
                       ' modify ',
                       column_name,
                       ' <new datatype> ',
                       if(is_nullable = 'NO', ' NOT ', ''),
                       ' NULL;')
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = '<your database>' 
    and column_type = '<old datatype>';
```

For instance, if you want to change columns from `tinyint(4)` to `bit(1)`, run it like this:

```
select distinct concat('alter table ',
                       table_name,
                       ' modify ',
                       column_name,
                       ' bit(1) ',
                       if(is_nullable = 'NO', ' NOT ', ''),
                       ' NULL;')
  from information_schema.columns
  where table_schema = 'MyDatabase' 
    and column_type = 'tinyint(4)';
```

and get an output like this:

```
alter table table1 modify finished bit(1)  NOT  NULL;
alter table table2 modify canItBeTrue bit(1)  NOT  NULL;
alter table table3 modify canBeNull bit(1)  NULL;
```

!! Does not keep unique constraints, but should be easily fixed with another `if`-parameter to `concat`. I'll leave it up to the reader to implement that if needed..

Answer (score 12):

```
Alter TABLE `tableName` MODIFY COLUMN `ColumnName` datatype(length);
```

**Ex :**

```
Alter TABLE `tbl_users` MODIFY COLUMN `dup` VARCHAR(120);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you want to alter the column details, set default value and add a comment, use this

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [new data type] 
DEFAULT [VALUE] COMMENT '[column comment]'
```

Answer (score 8):

> To change column data type there are **change**
>   method and **modify** method

```
ALTER TABLE student_info CHANGE roll_no roll_no VARCHAR(255);

ALTER TABLE student_info MODIFY roll_no VARCHAR(255);
```

> To change the field name also use the **change** method

```
ALTER TABLE student_info CHANGE roll_no identity_no VARCHAR(255);
```

Answer (score 6):

You use the `alter table ... change ...` method, for example:

```
mysql> create table yar (id int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into yar values(5);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> alter table yar change id id varchar(255);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> desc yar;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I believe it's MODIFY rather than change, but maybe both works.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

You can also set a default value for the column just add the DEFAULT keyword followed by the value.

```
ALTER TABLE [table_name] MODIFY [column_name] [NEW DATA TYPE] DEFAULT [VALUE];
```

This is also working for MariaDB (tested version 10.2)