# Change SQL Column Type

Tags: mysql

How to change the type of a column in SQL. For example the current type is char(2) I would like to make it char(20)?

```
ALTER TABLE test
ALTER COLUMN name char(20)
```

Comment: search first :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql

Comment: sorry I did not know what to search exactly for.. thank you for your suggestions

Comment: As a note, normally you would want `varchar()` rather than `char()`, unless you know the column consists of codes that are all exactly the same length (such as state abbreviations or airport codes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for MySql try:

```
ALTER TABLE test
MODIFY COLUMN name char(20)
```