# Alter table to modify column type not terminating

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I'm new to SQL and have a test table in a database. I realized that my previous title size allocation was too small, so I want to increase it from a VARCHAR(120) to VARCHAR(500) by running the following command:

`ALTER TABLE test MODIFY title VARCHAR(500);`

But that statement never terminates, even though the table contains less than 20 entries.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: I was basing that command off of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql), but I've also tried:

`ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN title VARCHAR(500);`

Which doesn't terminate either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not getting a syntax error and you have only a small number of rows, the most likely reason is that there is another process that's holding a lock on this table. Please connect any other clients that you have open. This could be other instances of mysql work bench, a long running script, the django console and so many things.

Then try the query again. If that still doesn't work, try `SHOW OPEN TABLES`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-open-tables.html

Comment: That was it, the mysql instance with the error I got earlier: `(1406, "Data too long for column 'title' at row 1")` which prompted me to increase varchar in the first place was still running in another screen.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN title VARCHAR(500);

Comment: Sorry...just noted this was MySQL. This is for SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Try this .
ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN column_name

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

`ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN title VARCHAR(500);`

I think you are missing the *keyword* `COLUMN`

Comment: The user of COLUMN is optional.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've also tried that command, same result.