# How to use a registered word in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, terminal

I want to create a table in which there is only one column with the title 'Div'. Can I create that table? According to my knowledge, 'DIV' is a registered keyword in MySQL. But I still tried this:

```
create table graduate ( div int );
```

and as expected made an error.

Comment: I am creating database on **MySQL**

Comment: try changing the name of that column instead of `div`

Comment: What does "div" mean in your table? Is it short for "division" or some other word? Use a more descriptive name for your column instead of a reserved word.

Comment: List of keywords and reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 4):

Really, you should not be using reserved words as identifiers.  If you feel you have to, use the backtick:

```
create table graduate (
    `div` int
);
```

Comment: How can we change the datatype of an existing column ?

Comment: @JSKrunner That's another question :) see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql