# Changing the column from varchar to int

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Hiya I am new to mySQL and picking it up relatively quickly.

However I needed to change the column from varchar to INT. [image: this needs to be int]

can someone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the data type for a column in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: If you have PHPMyAdmin or any other administration tool you can change the column very easy.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname INTEGER;
```

This is the SQL to do it.