# Date not saved correctly to MySQL

Tags: mysql, go, time

MySQL doesn't save the date properly.I am trying to add createdAt column in database.

I've tried using MySQL NOW() function already, but it doesn't seem to work.

// Go pseudo-code with sql query

```
stmt, _:= d.db.Prepare("INSERT INTO posts(title, body, EmailHref, SlackHref, DiscordHref, InstHref, Time) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW());")
res, err := stmt.Exec(newPost.Title, newPost.Body, newPost.EmailHref, newPost.SlackHref, newPost.DiscordHref, newPost.InstHref)
```

The type for createdAt column in MYSQL is DATE.

This is what I get when i fetch newly created post:

```
"time": "2019-04-24T00:00:00Z"
```

I expect to get actual time with up to minutes.

Comment: ok thanks everyone, your answers solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simple need to change the type from DATE to DATETIME in mySQL

```
alter table <tableName> modify <columnName> DATETIME;
```

Comment: @E.Belekov DATE is for storing dates, DATETIME for storing datetimes (dates with times), TIMESTAMPS also stores dates with times, are also faster, but datetime is easier to work with (timezones, sql native functions, ...)

Comment: DATE will simply show you only the date without any time. If you want to add the time you need to change your type to DATETIME or TIMESTAMP

Comment: Couldn't say it any better @PavelTřupek

Comment: Whose answer should I accept? You and Sebastian Brosch both answered at the same moment.

Comment: You can order on oldest an choose the oldest answer, the choice is yours :-)

Comment: Sorry for the fact that it's been 2 days, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to store the time too, you have to use `DATETIME` instead of `DATE`.

You can use the following query to [change the column type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql) of column `createdAt`:

```
ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY createdAt DATETIME
```

---

The `DATE` data type can't store a time part so you have to use `DATETIME`:

```
SELECT CAST(NOW() AS DATE);     -- 2019-04-24
SELECT CAST(NOW() AS DATETIME); -- 2019-04-24 09:47:57
```