# mysql field value should be greater than zero

Tags: mysql, sql

following is my table structure, i want to validate `price_list_rate` field, value should be greater than zero, i tried unsigned

`Version information: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2.1`

```
CREATE TABLE `price_list` (
`price_list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price_list_city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price_list_process_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price_list_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`price_list_rate` float UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`price_list_vendor_rate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created_by` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_by` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that for a price column, float is not a suitable data type. Decimal would be better.

Comment: Which MySQL version? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115497/check-constraint-in-mysql-is-not-working

Answer (score 5):

You need `check` constraint :

```
 ALTER TABLE `price_list`
    ADD CONSTRAINT chk_price CHECK (`price_list_rate` > 0);
```

Note : [CHECK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) constraint is available starts from MySQL `8.0.16` for older version you need trigger that prevents `0` price being inserting.

Comment: the table is already created, how to apply query to add ```CHECK```

Comment: @MacRathod `ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN`.

Comment: @MacRathod [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356875/3536236)

Comment: If MySQL 8.0.16, or later.

Comment: This solution adds table constraint, not field constraint. Although it solves the problem too.

Comment: i don't know, how to put trigger for that, can you plz help me??

Comment: @MacRathod. . . Trigger would be alternative.

Comment: @Akina it's older version, i've just mentioned in question after your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0.16 implemented the SQL CHECK constraint. Using this you can solve this problem

```
ALTER TABLE `price_list`
ADD CONSTRAINT min_price CHECK (`price_list_rate` > 0);
```

For earlier version you can use a CHECK constraint using a view WITH CHECK OPTION or a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

If your version does not support `CHECK` constraints then use

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_check_price_list_rate 
BEFORE INSERT
ON price_list
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.price_list_rate <= 0 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Error: `price_list`.`price_list_rate` must be positive.';
END IF;
END
```

and the same trigger for `BEFORE UPDATE` event.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b4d7e679ee37f42908d4640b0d3e2b1)