# Basic SpringBoot application throwing schema validation error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am getting below exception while running my SpringBoot application:

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id] in table [`my_table`]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]

below is the column definition for id in my entity class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
```

on database side the column is created like

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Can someone please help in resolving this.

Comment: Based on what the error message is telling you, either you need to change your DB column to a BIGINT or change your entity class to use Integer instead of Long for the id field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
> Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [id] in
> table [my_table]; **found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint
> (Types#BIGINT)]**

As highlighted, column id is a type of INTEGER and we specified Long(BIGINT for DB) in the entity. Mismatch in the datatypes causing the error message.

You can [change the database column type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356866/10961238) to BIGINT from INTEGER

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname columntype;
```

In case you do not have any SQL written to initialize the database. You may use the hibernate properties as follow

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create or update
```