# How to change data type in mysql cmd from int to date?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to change data type in mysql cmd from int to date?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a command:

ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname DATE;

For admin work I would suggest MySQL Workbench.

Right-click on table, select: Alter table and do what you need in the GUI such as change the type of data in under column: Datatype.