# Change data type of the attribute Roll-No of the table STUDENT from Number (10) to Varchar (10)

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, xampp

Here's what I wrote to update the data type of already existing column.

```
SELECT * FROM `student`;
ALTER TABLE student
ALTER COLUMN Roll_No VARCHAR(10) ;
```

But, after executing the SQL code, this shows an error in the syntax:-

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(10)' at line 2

What should be done to change data type of the attribute to another data type?

Comment: try `ALTER TABLE student MODIFY Roll_No VARCHAR(10);`

Comment: A simple search would have given you the answer in less time than it took to post this question. Does this answer your question? [How do I change the data type for a column in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql)