# How can i change column variable type in MySql workbench?

Tags: mysql

I was working on a database. then I set the data type of a simple place to INT. I want to change this. I need VARCHAR. how can I do it?. Can you help me to do this through Workbench or Python codes?

I searched a bit on the internet and looked through the documentation but I couldn't

I don't know much about MySQL. I only know simple things

Comment: Not hard to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysqlhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356866/how-do-i-change-the-data-type-for-a-column-in-mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html so what did you try and what problem did you encounter,

Comment: I encountered an error while accessing the page you sent. My problem is this. I am working on a project in Python. I set the column that used to be "Birtday" to INT. Then I was told that I had to use Datetime, so I used Datetime, but then the code was giving an error, so I wanted to convert the Datetime part to a string using str() and then send it to the database as VARCHAR. but i need to fix this as i already set it as INT

Comment: Are you looking for a purely python solution? Also birthday should be stored as date not varchar so what problem did you have with this?

Comment: I don't know much about mysql and data types. This project was requested in education. I wanted to use it as str(dt.date(age_year,age_month,age_day)) and pass it as VARCHAR. I found the solution thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change the datatype of a column in MySQL Workbench you can right-click your table and select `Alter Table`.
You will have a list of all available columns and their respective datatypes, which you will be able to change there. Clicking on `Apply` will generate the `ALTER TABLE` query which you can then apply.

If you want to change the datatype manually through a query you can do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `field_name` `field_name` VARCHAR(100);
```

Note that if you are trying to store a date of birth, it will be easier to use the `Datetime` datatype for your column. Depending on the language you're coding it, you will have access to a datetime variable which you will be able to format in any way you'd like.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very informative for MYSQL ignorant like me :)